# How to implement chat using bonjour service?

Tags: iphone, networking, chat, bonjour

I have one application in which all available clients are displayed.Now i want
to implement chatting between them.can it be done with help of bonjour service without
having any other server in between them?any tutorial or sample code for that?

Answer (score 2):

These links might be useful.

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

you can find source code on https://bitbucket.org/snej/chatty/src

thanks

Answer (score -1):

[Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) provides a high-level peer-to-peer connectivity API, which you can use for chat.